# How to detect dns server and ip-adresses in PHP

Tags: php, dns

I want to program a DNS-leaktester in PHP. Is it possible? or do I have to use other languages like python etc. to get the information.

Comment: I imagine anything that can be done in one language can be done in another in this case.  The language shouldn't really matter here.  How would you actually be performing the test?  That is, what do you need the language to *do*?  And, given that, what have you tried?

Comment: As a total side note I'd just like to point out that if anyone who knew enough to hack your site in a way that could be detected by this test would probably be knowledgable enough to spoof it, as well. I mean... this is how people "SWAT each other". Just food for thought.

Comment: I was just searching the checkdnsrr function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as well in PHP like in other languages. As for PHP try with:

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$dnsRecords = checkdnsrr($hostname);
```